# Jest encountered an unexpected token: React App with JS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, babel-jest

I can't manage to configure Jest and run tests. It's a very simple application in react, I'm using javascript and styled-component. I've been testing for a few days now.

Could someone give me a hint?

I get this message:

Details:

```
/.../node_modules/axios/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
  2 | import {Link, useLocation, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
> 3 | import axios from "axios";
    | ^
  4 | import {Wrapper, Container, Element, Pagination} from "./CharacterList.styled";
  5 | import titleImg from '../../images/title.png';
  6 |
```

this is my file: package.json.. e.g. I changed in scripts: "test": "jest --config jest.config.js",

```
    {
  "name": "dominika",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.4",
    "react-router": "^6.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --config jest.config.js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.3",
    "jest": "^27.4.5"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
}
```

this is jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
    testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css|less|scss|sss|styl)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules',
        '\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js'],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
    },

    transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
};
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why does this error occur?**

The 1.x.x version of axios changed the module type from CommonJS to ECMAScript.

**The 0.x.x version of axios index.js file**

```
module.exports = require('./lib/axios');
```

**The 1.x.x version of axiox index.js file**

```
import axios from './lib/axios.js';
export default axios;
```

Basically, jest runs on Node.js environment, so it uses modules following the CommonJS. If you want to use axios up to 1.x.x, you have to transpile the JavaScript module from ECMAScript type to CommonJS type. Jest ignores /node_modules/ directory to transform basically.

So you have to override transformIgnorePatterns option. There are two ways to override transformIgnorePatterns option.

**jest.config.js**

So how do you use config.js ,you can replace the parameter

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
```

on

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!axios)"],
```

**package.json**

you can add a setting for just in your package.json file

```
    {
  ...other options
  "jest": {
    "preset": "your project",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules\/(?!axios)"]
  }
}
```

**alternative solution**

in the package.json you can specify a parameter for the test script *"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/(?!axios)/"",*

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```